Simple Table of Contents in Rails is not working as intended
I had this thought of a simple Table of contents in Rails. I have created a new Rails 8 app, worked. I installed action text. Scaffold'ed out a post model with title and body. Body has the rich text and uses the trix editor. Post.rb model has the needed "has_rich_text :body". I went at this in a few different ways but finally landed on just grabbing the body in the model using "before_save" and making adjustments there. The concept is straight forward. When you create a new post, If you add a "heading" (will give you a h1 tag), then I can look through the body, grab those h1 tags, snatch the content, create the anchor tag from the content and modify the h1 to include the id attribute, which would also be the content.
I added the migration for adding "toc" to posts model where toc:rich_text. Ensured "has_rich_text :toc" was in the post.rb model and :toc was added to the strong params. Added the field in the _post.html.erb to show it. Here is my frustration. It works. Once the post is created I get the view with the links that are the heading in the post body. The h1 tags do not have the id attributes. Oh, but if I log it, the before save to body does have the modified code, after save, it is not there, but rather the original post body.
Here is the actions I am working on in the post.rb.
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :body
  has_rich_text :toc
  # has_rich_text :toc_body
  before_save :process_body

  private

  def process_body
    return if body.blank?

    # Convert the ActionText::RichText to a string
    body_content = body.to_s

    toc_data = generate_toc(body_content)

    # Log the modified body content
    # Rails.logger.debug("Modified Body: #{toc_data[:content]}")

    self.body = toc_data[:content]  # Store the modified body

    # Log the body after update
    # Rails.logger.debug("Body after update: #{self.toc_body}")

    self.toc = toc_data[:toc]        # Store the TOC
  end

  # Method to generate TOC and modify body
  def generate_toc(body)
    headings = body.scan(/<h1[^>]*>(.*?)<\/h1>/).flatten
    return { toc: "", content: body } if headings.empty?

    toc = "<ul>"
    ids = []  # Array to store generated IDs

    headings.each do |heading|
      id = heading.gsub(/\s+/, "-").downcase
      toc += "<li><a href='##{id}'>#{heading}</a></li>"
      ids << { heading: heading, id: id }  # Store heading and corresponding ID
    end

    # Manually build the new body content
    ids.each do |item|
      body.gsub!(/<h1>(#{Regexp.escape(item[:heading])})<\/h1>/, "<h1 id='#{item[:id]}'>\\1</h1>")
    end

    toc += "</ul>"

    { toc: toc.html_safe, content: body.html_safe }
  end
end

Here are the logs, I put bold ** around the points of interest to try and help:
Started POST "/posts" for ::1 at 2024-11-29 15:15:00 -0500
Processing by PostsController#create as TURBO_STREAM
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "post"=>{"title"=>"Ruby Blog", "body"=>"<h1>Chapter 1</h1><div>Rails is sunshine and lollipops</div><h1>Chapter 2</h1><div>Not everyone like Brussels Sprouts&nbsp;</div>"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-8.0.0/app/views/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb within layouts/action_text/contents/_content (Duration: 4.2ms | GC: 0.0ms)
**Modified Body:** <!-- BEGIN app/views/layouts/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb --><div class="trix-content">
  <!-- BEGIN vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-8.0.0/app/views/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb -->**<h1 id='chapter-1'>**Chapter 1</h1><div>Rails is sunshine and lollipops</div>**<h1 id='chapter-2'>**Chapter 2</h1><div>Not everyone like Brussels Sprouts&nbsp;</div>
<!-- END vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-8.0.0/app/views/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb --></div>
<!-- END app/views/layouts/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb -->
  Rendered vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-8.0.0/app/views/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb within layouts/action_text/contents/_content (Duration: 2.7ms | GC: 0.0ms)
**Body after update:** <!-- BEGIN app/views/layouts/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb --><div class="trix-content">
  <!-- BEGIN vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-8.0.0/app/views/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb --><div class="trix-content">
  **<h1>**Chapter 1</h1><div>Rails is sunshine and lollipops</div>**<h1>**Chapter 2</h1><div>Not everyone like Brussels Sprouts&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<!-- END vendor/bundle/ruby/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-8.0.0/app/views/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb --></div>
<!-- END app/views/layouts/action_text/contents/_content.html.erb -->

Another on a Slack channel suggested using Nokogiri. I installed the gem and rewrote the post.rb actions using it. I am still getting the same result. A helpful sort has suggested that the post.rb model may not be the best place for this. The best place I could think of to intercept and modify before save was the post model. I will think on this. Any advice would be appreciated. Here is the rewrite with Nokogiri:
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  # ActionText body
  has_rich_text :body
  # ActionText toc
  has_rich_text :toc

  # Use separate callbacks for create and update
  before_save :process_body

  private

  def process_body
    # Extract the HTML content from the rich text body
    body_content = body.to_trix_html

    # Make modifications and create toc
    result = generate_toc(body_content)

    self.toc = result[:toc]  # Update the TOC

    # Log result before save
    Rails.logger.debug("MODIFIED BODY BEFORE SAVE: #{result[:content]}")
    self.body = result[:content]  # Update the body with modified content
    # Log result after save
    Rails.logger.debug("BODY AFTER SAVE: #{self.body}")
  end

  def generate_toc(body)
    # Parse the HTML body with Nokogiri
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(body)

    # Find all <h1> tags
    headings = doc.css("h1")
    return { toc: "", content: body } if headings.empty?

    toc = "<ul>"

    headings.each do |heading|
      # Generate an ID for the heading
      id = heading.text.gsub(/\s+/, "-").downcase
      toc += "<li><a href='##{id}'>#{heading.text}</a></li>"

      # Set the ID attribute on the heading
      heading["id"] = id
    end

    toc += "</ul>"

    # Return the TOC and the modified content
    { toc: toc.html_safe, content: doc.to_html.html_safe }
  end
end

I would love any help here. At first I thought it was a issue with the loop and gsub, but now I am not so sure.

Just FYI: . does not match newlines, try /<h1[^>]*>(.*?)<\/h1>/m.

Thank you @WiktorStribiżew for the catch. That has been fixed. Problem still persist's but I think we knew that wasn't a solution, just regex being regex. lol. Thank you for the assist.

You're making this very hard on yourself and messy by generating HTML in the model. That belongs in the view or something like a helper or view component if you want to generate the HTML more programatically. I would put this hot mess down for a little bit and rethink your approach.

Also instead of  using a regex use Nokogiri (Rails already depends on it) to process the HTML and rails tag helpers to generate HTML programatically.

@max, I truly can't thank you enough for the positive and thoughtful solution. The one bit of advice that tipped toward a solution may have been the use of Nokogiri. I did recreate the post.rb model actions using the gem. Same outcome. I will edit the original to include that work as well. "Make it work, Make it clean, Make it fast." and thanks again for your support!

@Developer3027 sorry if that come out a bit harsh. Making it work is actually a lot easier and faster if you separate it out into parts that can be tested in isolation instead of monster methods inside your model. It's not really a matter of clean code, it's a matter of working efficiently as it lets you have a bit of confidence in your code.

Don't make your model do everything. It already has more than enough responisbilites without adding HTML processing and generation to the list.
Start with the job of extracting out the headers from the body:
# Extacts the headers from a chunk of HTML and adds ids for anchor links
class Outliner
  def initialize(html)
    @document = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(html)
  end

  # not the most elegant signature ever but works
  def perform
     headers = @document.css("h1")
             .map do |node|
                id = title_to_anchor(node.text)
                node[:id] = id # mutates the document
                { id: id, text: node.text }
             end
    [ headers, @document ]
  end

  def self.perform(html)
    new(html).perform
  end

  private
  # This is an extremely naive implementation for a pretty complex problem - YMMV
  def title_to_anchor(title)
    title.parameterize
  end
end

# require "test_helper"
class OutlinerTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @html = <<~HEREDOC
      <div>
        <h1>Header 1</h1>
        <h1>Header 2</h1>
      </div>
    HEREDOC
  end

  test "it extracts the text and a parameterized id" do
    expected =  [
                  { text: "Header 1", id: "header-1" },
                  { text: "Header 2", id: "header-2" }
                ]
    assert_equal expected, Outliner.perform(@html).first
  end
  test "it adds id's to the headers" do
    doc = Outliner.perform(@html).last
    binding.break
    assert_equal "Header 2", doc.css("#header-2").text
  end
end

This is just a Plain Old Ruby Object amd easy to test as it just does one thing - HTML parsing.
Modifying the document at the same time is a bit dirty but a compromise so that we don't have to process the HTML fragment twice which can be expensive.
Note that just dasherizing the header text is a very naive implementation and will cause issues if/when the titles collide with other elements on the page.
And then we will give generating the table of contents the same treatment:
# Creates a Table of Contents from a list of headers
class OutlineGenerator

  def initialize(headers)
    @headers = headers
    @context = ApplicationController.new.view_context
  end

  # This isn't the most elegant solution ever
  # alternatives would be to use context.render_to_string to render a ERB template
  # or view components
  def perform
    @context.tag.ul do |builder|
      @headers.each do |h|
        a =  builder.a(h[:text], href: "#" + h[:id])
        @context.concat(builder.li(a)) # writes the content into the string buffer
      end
    end
  end

  def self.perform(headers)
    new(headers).perform
  end
end

require "test_helper"
class OutlineGeneratorTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  setup do
    @headers = [
      { text: "Header 1", id: "header-1" },
      { text: "Header 2", id: "header-2" }
    ]
  end

  test "it generates a list" do
    html = '<ul><li><a href="#header-1">Header 1</a></li><li><a href="#header-2">Header 2</a></li></ul>'
    assert_equal html, OutlineGenerator.perform(@headers)
  end
end

This isn't the most elegant solution ever, alternatives would be to use @context.render_to_string to render a ERB template or libraries like ViewComponents. The important part here is just that your model should not have to care about the details of how the HTML is generated.
Then the model just has to worry about updating the attributes:
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  def process_body
    headers, document = Outliner.perform(body.to_trix_html)
    return unless headers.any?
    self.body = document.to_html
    self.toc = OutlineGenerator.perform(headers)
  end
end

Note that using a callback isn't the only way (and maybe not the best way) to go about this. You might want to consider moving it into a ActiveJob for example so that you can offload the processing to a background process instead of making the web tread wait.

Seriously @max. Thank you. This was way more than I would have ever expected and now I do see what you were talking about. I had ran across an article today Rails TOC that I have been reviewing. This rocks sir, thank you. Solid +

seriously @Developer3027 you need to make this the "accepted answer", it's brilliant
